# Creating a Python pipeline to convert data

Tags: python

Good day to you all,

I am pretty unexperienced with Python, and would like to ask if you can help me out how to build a pipeline in Python. First importing a csv file (no streaming data) into Python and converting this data file  so I can use the converted data in machine learning analysis.

For some time I have been using software that generates strategy code to trade the stock market.
This software combines different indicators. Before you start building strategies you have to manually set the number of indicators between 1 and 5. 
In case of 1 indicator the log file contains only one column with indicators. It would be nice if the Python code recognizes the number of indicators used in the data file and converts all the data.
For example, I set the number of indicators to 3. After the build process the log file looks like this:

```
GSB_ID          Indic. 1 ID     Indic. 2 ID     Indic. 3 ID
125783-x8nh6    DMIMinus        AdaptiveMovAvg  DMIMinus
042610-UuLxc    DMIMinus        GSB_Highest     ADXR
544959-uZimb    ADXR            AvgTrueRange    DMIMinus
204155-NxrYo    AdaptiveMovAvg  GSB_Highest     GSB_Highest
```

Column1 shows the strategy name. 
Column2 to 4 the 3 indicators used. Usually there are 3 different indicators per strategy, but sometimes the same indicator is used more than once. For example the strategy shown in the first row: DMIMinus is used twice in this strategy.

Converting pipeline:
For every strategy (row) I would like to see the number of times an indicator is used. I would like to convert the log file shown into something like this:

```
GSB_ID AdaptiveMovAvg ADXR AvgTrueRange DMIMinus GSB_Highest
125783-x8nh6    1   0   0   2   0
042610-UuLxc    0   1   0   1   1
544959-uZimb    0   1   1   1   0
204155-NxrYo    1   0   0   0   2
```

So for the strategy in the first row: AdaptiveMovAvg is used once (1) and DMIMinus is used twice (2).

Some more info about the data:
The log file can contains up to 100,000 strategies (rows).
The software can use up to 100 different indicators, so converting would give 100 different columns. Sometimes new indicators are added, so some flexibility would be nice.

I would really appreciate it if you can help me into the right direction setting this up in Python. Thanks in advance!

All the best and thanks again for your help,
Sharon

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.  [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: There are numerous ways to approach this. You have *table-like* data and you are aggregating. Keeping the data in a [database](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) seems reasonable or using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html) to parse and aggregate would work. You could also just make a dictionary/namedtuple for each strategy then aggregate those into a big dictionary.

Comment: Perhaps you should read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
from collections import Counter
def read_and_transform_log_file():
    all_indicators = set()
    data = []

    with open("logfile.txt", "r") as input_data:
        input_data.readline()
        for line in input_data:
            strategy, *indicators = line.strip().split()
            indicators = Counter(indicators)
            all_indicators.update(indicators.keys())
            data.append((strategy, indicators))

    all_indicators = list(all_indicators)
    with open("output.txt", "w") as output:
        print("\t".join(["GSB_ID"] + all_indicators), file=output)
        for strategy, indicators in data:
            row = [strategy] + [str(indicators.get(x, 0)) for x in all_indicators]
            print("\t".join(row), file=output)
```

which outputs

```
GSB_ID  ADXR    DMIMinus    AdaptiveMovAvg  GSB_Highest AvgTrueRange
125783-x8nh6    0   2   1   0   0
042610-UuLxc    1   1   0   1   0
544959-uZimb    1   1   0   0   1
204155-NxrYo    0   0   1   2   0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help MindOfMetalAndWheels and wwii! Have a weekend and stay safe